# Lightbox 2 - Image Clicks Through to New Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

I've added the files and linked the CSS in my header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I believe that I have linked the jquery and lightbox.js files as well (within my body tag, below the rest of my markup)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is my HTML

```
<li><a href="images/video-player-placeholder-very-large.png" class="landscape-small overlay red" data-lightbox="project1"><img src="images/video-player-placeholder-very-large.png"/></a></li>
```

The result is an image that clicks through to a new page. I do not see any console errors when I inspect the page. All files currently reside on my local drive. Could this be an issue?

Comment: You seem to be loading jQuery twice, your own version and a version that's bundled with lightbox.

Comment: Not really sure how that could be happening?

Comment: You add it once in your first script tag (`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>`) and then again in the second script tag when you load the combined file (`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
`)

Comment: From http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/: Make sure jQuery, which is required by Lightbox, is also loaded.

If you already use jQuery on your page, make sure it is loaded before lightbox.js. jQuery 1.7 or greater is required.
If you are not currently using jQuery, I've created a packaged file that includes both Lightbox and jQuery. Include dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js instead of lightbox.js.

Comment: I see. Now I understand better. I've removed the first script tag but the result is still the same.

Comment: Still no errors in the console? And you're sure the .css and .js files exist in the paths you specified? Do you have an example we can see?

Comment: It works! I copied the js and css files over to my project folders again. I must have missed something the first time. Appreciate your time.